# How to submit form data to a external URL using C# in my .NET Core 5 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to send form data to an external URI and get the response which is a page redirect.  I've written the code to do this but the remote server isn't accepting it, the reasons are not specified.  If I create the form in a HTML page and submit it from there, it works perfectly.

Here is the form I need to submit:

```
<form action="https://someurl.com/make" method=POST>
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="42">
    <input type="hidden" name="version" value="123">
    <input type=submit value="Send">
</form>
```

So, to send this form data to `someurl.com` instead of the user having to do it, I tried to use a `WebClient` because I'm posting to an external URL for this, I also use string interpolation for values that are passed when this is called.

```
public async Task<string> Send_Version(string versionNumber = "0")
{
    try
    {
        string html = $"test=42&version={versionNumber}";

        using (WebClient webclient = new())
        {
            webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string pagesource = webclient.UploadString("www.someurl.com/make", html);
            
            return pagesource.ToString();
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorString = $"Error";
            return errorString;
        }            
    }
```

As you can see I use the `WebClient` so that is disposes correctly, I add a `Content-Type` and then I `UploadString` via the web client with both the URL and my data `html`.

The remote server doesn't like this way of doing it but my question is, does this look accurate for posting form data to a remote url with c# or have I missed something critical?

Comment: This looks fine to me, personally I prefer using HttpClient but that's beside the point. The only thing I can think you might be doing, is that it looks like you want to pass the 'html' variable as query string parameters, where as I think the method 'UploadString' passes it in the request body.

Comment: So this might be a hacky way to go about it, but instead: webclient.UploadString($"www.someurl.com/make?{html}", null); I would just recommend using the HttpClient instead though, makes things a lot simpler.

Comment: You need to look closer at the browser dev tools when the browser is submitting a working request; could be anything that your server dislikes, that differs. Maybe it doesn't like the User-Agent, maybe you're not sending one when you should, or a cookie, or maybe some script on the page is being run by the browser and it's causing some vital thing to happen server end, or CORS.. or.. or.. Ultimately the server is known to respond well when your browser sends X.. Your code is sending Y, and the server doesn't like it for some reason that will be explained by a difference between the two

Comment: (If you replicated everything perfectly, the server wouldn;t be able to tell the diffrence between your code and your browser. Generally you can get away with *not* replicating perfectly and the server will still work, but there's some intrinsic limit as to how far you can deviate from what the server expects and it still be able to cope. The usual no-nos are user agents, cookies, content encoding but I've seen all sorts)

Comment: @DubDub *where as I think the method 'UploadString' passes it in the request body* - `<form` is POST. `UploadString` is POST

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your C# code with one of my APIs, and it's working fine. The only finding is:

If it works

```
<form action="https://someurl.com/make" method=POST>
```

Then try keeping the URL the same as used in HTML

```
string pagesource = webclient.UploadString("https://someurl.com/make", HTML);
```

Also, if it is not the URL issue, then please share the exception details.